# Youtube api search keywords issue

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to search with "Basics of HACCP|Network Security|Leadership|Appendages|Moving Vehicles|VCA Basis|My Interactive video Course|How to charge your Tesla|Odfjell Demo|Test Arjo|Mongos Demo|My first course in edl|Course MMoonen" no results found.

If i replace `MMoonen` with `Monen` getting videos matching.

Search Query should match either words

Whats issue cause results empty?

Comment: Maybe the misspelling of `MMoonen` and `Monen` is the problem? - share the request you're making for test it [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true) - PS. don't include your API KEY.

Comment: I made this [sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22q%22%3A%22Basics%20of%20HACCP%7CNetwork%20Security%7CLeadership%7CAppendages%7CMoving%20Vehicles%7CVCA%20Basis%7CMy%20Interactive%20video%20Course%7CHow%20to%20charge%20your%20Tesla%7COdfjell%20Demo%7CTest%20Arjo%7CMongos%20Demo%7CMy%20first%20course%20in%20edl%7CCourse%20MMoonen%22%7D) and it gets results - please confirm.

Comment: i'm filtering with `type:video` then no results found. thank you for your time.